# Как решить диф. уравнение с помощью правила Симпсона(3/8)?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, mathematica

Как решить диф. уравнение **y' = y<sup>2</sup> e<sup>x</sup> - 2y , y(0) = 2** с помощью формулы Симпсона(3/8)?

Пробовала сделать на пакете Mathematica. Работает только с функцией  1 + e<sup>-x</sup> sin[8 x<sup><sup>2</sup>/<sub>3</sub></sup>]`.

```
  Simpson38[a0_, b0_, m0_] := 
  Module[{a = N[a0], b = N[b0], h, m = m0, X}, h = (b - a)/(3*m); 
   Subscript[X, k_] = a + k*h; 
   Return[((3*h)/8)*
     Sum[f[Subscript[X, 3*k - 3]] + 3*f[Subscript[X, 3*k - 2]] + 
       3*f[Subscript[X, 3*k - 1]] + f[Subscript[X, 3*k]], {k, 1, 
       m}]];];
f[x_, y_] = y*y*Exp[x] - 2*y;
a = 0.;
b = 2;
M = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 
   35, 40};
tbl = Table[j, {j, 1, 20}];
Print[""];
For[j = 1, j <= 20, j++, 
  tbl[[j]] = {M[[j]], NumberForm[Simpson38[a, b, M[[j]]], {8, 6}]};];
Print[TableForm[tbl, 
   TableHeadings -> {None, {"m sample points", "Simpson38[a,b,m]"}}, 
   TableSpacing -> {2, 1}]];
Needs["Graphics`Colors`"];
Plot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2.01}, {0, 2.01}}, 
  Ticks -> {Range[0, 2, 0.5], Range[0, 2, 0.5]}, Axes -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> Magenta];
```

Comment: А минус за что?

Comment: @KromStern, потёр. В [описание метки](//ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/mathematica/info) не заглянешь, утвердить бы его.